# How to increment xpath using loop?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate timesheet where 5 webelements have the -

> id='ddlIN_HH_1', ddlIN_HH_2, ddlIN_HH_3, ddlIN_HH_4, ddlIN_HH_5

Now if I use

```
Select s= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@id,'ddlIN_HH_')]")));
 s.selectByValue("09");
```

How do I set the same value for the other webelements??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of findElement, use findElements. Something like,

```
List<WebElement> dds = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[contains(@id,'ddlIN_HH_')]"))

for(dd : dds){
    Select s= new Select(dd);
    s.selectByValue("09");
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can restrict to first 5 webelements??